# Round to 4 Decimal places not working?

Tags: c#, format, decimal

Doing this:

```
double dblRateEvalResult = -0.52;
string strNewResult = dblRateEvalResult.ToString("000.####").TrimStart('-');
```

I want:

```
000.5200
```

I get:

```
000.52
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `0` custom specifier instead of `#`

```
string str =  dblRateEvalResult.ToString("000.0000").TrimStart('-');
```

*(In your code you are trying to assign string to a double value, I guess this is a typo)*

See: [The "0" custom format specifier - Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0)

> If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the
>   result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string.

Comment: And yes, that double/string was a typo... I updated my question correctly

Comment: Just a side question - does this mean I could use any character in place of the `0`?

Comment: @FastTrack, No I don't think so, you will find more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0